# Finding Fibonacci series in python using def function

Tags: python

I am beginner in python and and i am trying to find fibonacci series of print the first 10 numbers in the Fibonacci series and i am not getting expected output.

Here is code which i have written:

```
def fibonacci_with_loop(n):
    fib_series = [0, 1]

    for i in range(2, n):
        next_number = fib_series[-1] + fib_series[-2]
        fib_series.append(next_number)

    print (fib_series)
```

Comment: Prints the sequence just fine to me, so I'm not sure what you expected. Perhaps you also wanted to store this output with a `return` statement?

Comment: Not very efficient  but your code is functionally correct

Comment: its returning only one value i want to print till 10 value

Comment: The only value that your function returns is None

Comment: ok how to print can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the function you wrote, you need to write fibonacci_with_loop() at the end of your code. Could you have forgotten this?

Comment: Perhaps you can show it.